# An algebra with a strictly positive state + condition ? to become a C$^*$-algebra.

Tags: spectral-theory, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $(A,*)$ be an involutive $\mathbb{C}$-algebra i.e. a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra with a semi-linear anti-automorphism i.e.
identically

1. $(x+y)^*=x^*+y^*$

   $(\alpha.x)^*=\overline{\alpha}.x^*$

   $(xy)^*=y^*x^*$

A strictly positive (or faithful) state $\varphi\in A^*$ is such that for all $x\in A\setminus \{0\}$, $\varphi(x^*x)> 0$. 
One can prove easily that $g(x,y):=\varphi(x^*y)$ is a non-degenerate hermitian form. It can be noted that, due to the fact that $g(a.x,y)=g(x,a^*y)$ and with finite dimensionality, one gets that $A$ is semi-simple. So, one can consider $A$ as simple.

My question is the following.

Q) We suppose $A$ to be finite dimensional. Under which additional condition(s) is the Hilbert space $(A,g)$ a C$^*$-algebra ?

**Late edit** I insist on the fact that I am in search of conditions for
$(A,g)$ to be a C$^*$-algebra, not only $A$. This means that it should be a C$^*$-algebra for the precise norm $||x||=\sqrt{g(x,x)}$.

**Late remark** The fact that $A$ be a star-algebra of finite dimension, sum of matrix algebras is by no means sufficient to imply that the projectors on the blocks are *-invariant nor $A\simeq \mathbb{C}$ as shows the following counterexample. Take $B=\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ (algebra of complex square matrices of dimension $n>0$) and $A=B\oplus B$ with the anti-automorphism
$(X,Y)^\star=(Y^*,X^*)$. Then $(A,\star)$ is easily checked to be a star algebra. It is of finite dimension, sum of matrix algebras but $dim_\mathbb{C}=2n^2\not= 1$. Indeed, the existence of a strictly positive state is crucial as there is none over $A$.

Comment: I guess you mean $\varphi(x^*x)>0$ in the definition?

Comment: Oh, yes ... thanks (+1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following statements are equivalent:

- $A$ is a C$^*$-algebra with the norm induced by $\varphi$
- $\dim A=1$, i.e., $A=\mathbb C$

*Proof.* if $A=\mathbb C$, then the only state is the identity, which induces the norm.

Conversely, if $A$ is a C$^*$-algebra, its norm satisfies the C$^*$-identity
$$\tag1\|x\|^2=\|x^*x\|.$$ In terms of $\varphi$, this is
$$\tag2\varphi(x^*x)=\varphi((x^*x)^2)^{1/2},\qquad x\in A.$$
So, for each positive $a\in A$,
$$\tag3\varphi(a)^2=\varphi(a^2).$$
As $\varphi$ is a ucp map, the equality $(3)$ says that $a$ is in the multiplicative domain of $\varphi$. Thus the multiplicative domain of $\varphi$ is all of $A$, since a C$^*$-algebra is spanned by its positive elements. So $\varphi$ is a faithful representation of $A$ into (thus onto) $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Very interesting (+1). I do not know what is a "ucp map" can you say a word on this (and, if needed, what its "multiplicative domain" is). Thanks in advance.

Comment: "ucp" means "unital, completely positive". I don't have references at  hand now, but I'll post some tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks in advance (+1)

Comment: @Martin Argerami. A reference for the words you use is the Brown-Ozawa book.

Comment: @QuantumSpace: yes. And in Paulsen's, in Pisier's, in Blecher-LeMerdy's, and others. But I have always felt that saying "x is in book A" is really poor form, so I try to give at least a section number. Which I will, soon.

Comment: Thank you for the fruitful interaction (+1)

Comment: Well, I don't want to be lazy: You can read the basics about completely positive maps in section 1.5, p10 of the book "$C^*$-algebras and finite-dimensional approximations by Brown and Ozawa. In that same section, on p12, multiplicative domains are also discussed.

Comment: But I guess Paulsen's book is a book in which more information can be found, but I recently read parts of the BO book and I liked the writing style.

Comment: Ok, now I'm not on a phone. For starters, Brown-Ozawa's book as mentioned by QuantumSpace is a good read. Paulsen's *Completely Bounded Maps and Operator Algebras* covers completely positive maps in Chapter 3; the multiplicative domain is right at the end on page 37. In Blecher-LeMerdy's *Operator Algebras and Their Modules*, one should look at section 1.3, and in particular Proposition 1.3.11. Pisier (*Operator Space Theory*) considers cp maps in chapter 1, and the multiplicative domain in Lemma 14.2.

Comment: Very nice review !

Comment: @MartinArgerami  You where right in using $\varphi$ in your analysis, the existence of a strictly positive state is crucial (see my late remark).

Answer (score 4):

No  Hilbert space is a $C^*$-algebra in any natural way since the structure of Hilbert spaces (a vector  space with an inner
product) is quite different from that of  a C*-algebra (a Banach space equipped with an involutive algebra structure).

Nevertheless from the data provided by the OP one may give  $A$ the structure of a  $C^*$-algebra in a very natural
way.  The first step is to consider the hermitian form $g$ as an inner product on $A$, so that
$$
  H:= (A,g)
  $$
becomes a Hilbert space
(completeness follows from  finite dimensionality).
One may  then define  a map
$$
  \pi :A\to B(H),
  $$
by
$$
  \pi (a)\xi  = a\xi , \quad\forall a\in  A,\quad \forall \xi \in H,
  $$
(here $a\xi $ is nothing other than  the product of $a$ and $\xi $).

One may easily show that $\pi $ is a *-homomorphism.  It is moreover injective since, for $a\neq 0$, one has that
$\pi (a)a^*=aa^*\neq 0$, as a consequence of $\varphi (aa^*)>0$.

Finally,  identifying $A$ with its image within $B(H)$ via $\pi $, we  have  that $A$ becomes a $C^*$-algebra.

---

**Later edit**:
The late edit indeed makes the question trivial and, as noted my Martin, the only example is the complex numbers.

A perhaps more elementary proof of this fact is that every finite dimensional $C^*$-algebra is the direct sum of matrix algebras, so unless $\text{dim}(A)=1$, there exists a pair of mutually orthogonal projections $p$ and $q$.  It follows that  $\|p\pm q\|=1$, hence the parallelogram law fails.

Comment: Thank you. Sounds good at first sight (+1). Must go into details tomorrow. Note that, due to the fact that $g(a.x,y)=g(x,a^*y)$ and with finite dimensionality, one gets that $A$ is semi-simple. Of course one cannot take $\xi=0$.

Comment: The formula $\pi(a)\xi=a\xi$ is the **definition** of $\pi$ so I don't understand what do you mean when you say *it is not true*.

Comment: If $\pi(a)=0$, then $aa^*=\pi(a)a^*=0$, whence $a=0$  by hypothesis.

Comment: Each $\pi(a)$ may fail to be injective but $\pi$ is injective.

Comment: Perhaps you should read about the GNS representation, which you will find in any basic C"-algebra book.